# Keycloak local installation returns "403 - forbidden" on localhost:8080, but on browser and wget

Tags: keycloak

I have Keycloak installed on a Windows 10 machine from an old Keycloak-3.4.3-Final (Keycloak+Wildfly) package (I need to run a few tests on this version).

After successful installation (0 error), I ran kcadm CLI against localhost:8080, all went well.

But, when I tried wget against http://localhost:8080 and in laptop's browser, I got "403 - Forbidden".

One thing to mention: the original package did not have welcome-content directory, thus there was one error in executing standalone.sh/bat. after I added the directory (empty), standalone.sh/bat completed with 0 error.

Any suggestions?